# Multiple poisson processes ?

Tags: poisson-distribution, model, poisson-process

I'm just trying to get my head around Poisson processes, as they're fairly new to me, and I've had a thought experiment that has been annoying me a little. Imagine a volume of some mixture hit by X-rays of a certain energy. For this toy problem, imagine just one photon in a given time interval. The interaction cross-section we'll call $\sigma$. Now, the mixture is made up of different substances, and the fraction $V_{D}$ corresponds to the proportional of the mixture made of molecule $D$. By my understanding of the process, the odds of at least one interaction of that photon with $D$ in a time interval $t$ is

$P(X > 0) = D_{E} =  1 - e^{-\sigma V_{D} t}$

I derived this result by subtracting the probability of no interaction from 1. Now, if that's correct imagine that this interaction excites $D$, and excited $D$ can interact with substance $O$ if it's close enough to it. There is only a very small quantity of $O$ in the material, with fraction $V_{O}$. Now, one could reason that as this fraction is tiny and these are essentially independent events, then the odds of both exciting $D$ and having it interact with $O$ (assuming roughly homogenous spread) would be simply

$P_{1} = V_{O}D_{E}$

However, because $V_{O}$ is so low, perhaps I may equally reason that the odds of $D_{E}$ interacting with $O$ are so low that it is itself a Poisson process, so that

$P_{2} = 1 - e^{-V_{O}D_{E}} = 1 - e^{-V_{O}(1 - e^{-\sigma V_{D} t})}$

This is potentially a very stupid question as I must be misunderstanding some aspect of the principle, but thought I'd ask here -Firstly, are multiple Poisson events possible, and in the toy problem posed here, which approach (if any) should be taken?